# Given a string denoting a type, I need to know if it's a value or reference type

Tags: c#, types, t4

I'm writing a T4 template and got stuck on this. If consumers of the template write:

```
Please generate stuff for: string myString
```

I need to generate

```
if (myString != null)
{
    DoStuffWith(myString)
}
```

Whereas if they write

```
Please generate stuff for: int myInt
```

I need to generate simply

```
DoStuffWith(myInt)
```

And this needs to work with custom value/reference types too.

If I forced the template consumers to write `System.String myString` or `System.Int32 myInt`, I imagine this could be done without trouble; there's presumably some `GetTypeFromFullTypeName` method hiding in the framework somewhere. But I don't want to make them do that.

Any ideas on how my T4 template could get at this information, so I could conditionally generate the right code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get the corresponding instance of the `Type` class (i.e. `Type.GetType` or `Assembly.GetType`).
2. Check the `IsValueType` property.

The number of types with "short names" is very limited, they're actually C# keywords.  So you can use a case statement, e.g. `case "string": return typeof (string);`

You'll also need some rules for `?`, and for finding a specific concrete version of generic classes (recursion will be helpful).  Don't try to translate `int?` into ``` System.Nullable``1[System.Int32] ```, instead use `typeof(System.Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(FindType("int"))`.

Comment: Step 1 is what I'm stuck on; in particular the translation from `string` to `System.String` or `int?` to `System.Nullable\`1[System.Int32]`

Comment: @Domenic: See edit, which I already put in after rereading the question.

Comment: Thanks, this will probably be what I go with and accept, albeit with special handling for nullables and generics (fun times...).

Comment: How'd you get a single backtick into your comment?

Comment: After some trial and error putting a \ before the backtick did the trick. And thanks especially for that nullable trick!

Comment: nope, just found the code, and it goes the other direction, converts any `System.Type` to a nice human-readable string (e.g. `typeof(System.UInt64)` becomes "ulong", `typeof<(int?)` becomes "System.Nullable<int>" and not what you said in your comment.  But not helpful for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You could emit the null check always, even for value types. This is not a compiler error, but produces a [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228621.aspx) which you could [suppress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys.aspx):

```
#pragma warning disable CS0472 
if (myInt != null)
{
    DoStuffWith(myInt)
}
#pragma warning restore CS0472
```

Comment: Yeah, I just realize this worked after posting, but I'm trying to generate nice code if possible; this code won't be hidden behind a `#region Tool generated`, but instead be the starting point from which developers will build customizations.